# Create a wrapper for HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, http

So im pretty new to programming  so bear with me,

So i've made a simple program that sends a HttpGet and get the respons from the server and some other stuff.
But now I want to implement in a wrapper or something ,so that I can call apon an httpclient with my extra code so I can reuse that code when I need it

So could someone give me an example on how too do it ?

Comment: I know SO is a coding site, so we shouldn't worry too much about English usage - but if you ask people to "Bare with me"..... I find this very funny

Comment: May be by overriding some methods of **httpclient** you can change  behavior by reusing some parts of  **httpclient** ?

Comment: I would love an example ask I'm stuck on how to do it and my mind isnt clearing up :/